# Let's encrypt with Auth Basic + HTTPS only

Tags: lets-encrypt, traefik

I would like to create a frontend to go on the traefik's dashboard, so here it's what I did:

```
[file]
  [frontends]
    [frontends.traefik]
      entrypoints = ["https"]
      backend = "traefik"
      basicAuth = [
        "...:...",
      ]
    [frontends.traefik.routes.route]
      rule = "Host:t.foo.bar"
  [backends]
    [backends.traefik]
      [backends.traefik.servers.server]
        url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080"
```

But the certificate is not valid. I guess it's because I force https, and I have a auth basic.

What should I do?
I guess I would need to create an other frontend on the same domain with `/.well-known` check and don't have http basic on this frontend ?

Comment: Can you clarify what "the certificate is not valid" means?

Comment: I guess it's because the certificate is not validated by Let's encrypt (I see this: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/what-does-your-connection-is-not-secure-mean )

Comment: Why do you guess that? How did you determine it is not valid?

Comment: Because when I go on the domain, I see this message (previous link)

Comment: And you are sure that the domain you're using to open that website matches the domain used for the certificate?

Comment: That the job of traefik... so yes